# Field results as headers in cgridview

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I'm currently setting up a gridview where each result of a field in one table will need to become a header

Unfortunatly I can't seem to find a way that will set the values to be the header while also allowing a value in another table

For example, I need to have every result in the name field be the header for my cgridview

[image]
Then every result that links up to the header for the value to also appear as the value for this header

[image]

My guess is that somehow I would add the results to a dataprovider, loop round the dataprovider for results to fill the columns and use this function as the result for the gridview but the page breaks if I do not strictly define columns

The issue I'm having is that the column is still displaying as the HEADER1 rather than the data, and the data is simply the data I'm pulling

```
public function exportSearch($event_id){

        $query = "SELECT
                    u.prefix AS  'Title', 
                    u.forename AS  'Forename', 
                    u.surname AS  'Surname', 
                    u.telephone AS 'Mobile Number',
                    u.email AS  'Email Address', 
                    ea.checkin_status_id AS 'checked in',
                    u.update_time AS  'Register Date', 
                    eg.name AS 'Event Group Registered', 
                    e.name AS  'Session Registered', 
                    u.bio AS 'User Information',
                    u.dob AS 'Date of Birth',
                    u.company AS 'Company',
                    u.company_role AS 'Company Role',
                    CONCAT(u2.forename, ' ', u2.surname) AS 'Guest of',
                    MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 1 THEN uv.name ELSE NULL END) AS Header1,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 1 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS Question1,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 2 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS Question2,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 3 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS Question3,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 4 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS Question4,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 5 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS Question5,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 6 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS Question6

                    FROM tbl_event_attendees AS ea

                    LEFT JOIN tbl_user AS u ON ea.user_id = u.id
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_event AS e ON ea.event_id = e.id
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_event_groups AS eg on e.group_id = eg.id
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_user AS u2 ON ea.guest_of_user_id = u2.id
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_user_variables AS uv on u.id = uv.user_id

                    WHERE ea.event_id = {$event_id}

                    GROUP BY ea.id";




        $count=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryScalar();
        return $sqlDataprovider = new CSqlDataProvider($query, array(
                'totalItemCount'=>$count,
                'sort'=>array(
                    'attributes'=>array(
                    )
                ),
                'pagination'=>array(
                'pageSize'=>$count, //Show all records
        ),
            ));
     }
```

and my view

```
array(
            'header' => $data['Header1'],
            'name' => 'Header1',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => $data['Question6'],
        ),
```

and the result is simply inputting what I want as the header into the value, and the AS identifier as the header.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use header property of the columns

```
array('name'=>'yoir_column_name',
  'header'=> '$your_value_from_db_for_header',
 ),
```

should be somethings like this

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'your_id',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(
        'your_first_column' ,
        'your_second_column',
         array(
            'header'=> $data['Header1'],
            'value'=> '$data->Question6',
            'name'=> 'Question6',
        ),
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is working. 

As I'm grabbing it from a select query, I am inputting it like this. I have added my query to the above question

 array(
            'header' => $data['Header1'],
            'name' => 'Header1',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => $data['Question6'],
        ),

Comment: I have added a sample  hope useful

Comment: Hi. I have tried $data['Header1'], but it only returns it as Question6, any ideas?

Comment: try name  = ''    and are you shure that $data['Header1'], is not empty?

Comment: If I put $data['Header1'] into the value field it populates correctly. but does not populate in the header field.

Comment: then try   'header'=> "$data['Header1']",

Comment: I will give that a shot when I get back in the office, cheers.

Comment: This completely errors out the page, Running out of ideas now.

Comment: the is html encoded?  .  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridColumn#header-detail

Comment: I'm not sure. How would I go about this? chtml::value thenpassing data?

Comment: Is an html  result so  .. html encoded .. but i think the problem is related to the fact the header can evaluate properly the varc you passed .. because with a letteral work ..

Comment: Yep. Fairly think I'm out of solutions now for this. Never imagined Yii would be so closed off.